# How to change bluetooth maximum volume with mixer_paths.xml?

Tags: bluetooth, volume

As question title, I want to change the bluetooth overall volume doing some changes in mixer_paths.xml (if possible). The problem is, that I don't know what variable to change.

With the same phone, but different ROMs, the output voltage of bluetooth receiver vary from 0.8Vrms to 1.1Vrms. The bluetooth device is an LDAC / AptX -> I2S -> DAC, which should be able to output a good 2Vrms of voltage, but I can't fully exploit it.